# Delete a specific button in a table in js

Tags: javascript, html

I have a little todo table with JS. It adds every time you type in a new task two new rows in a table which contains the task and a button to delete it again.

Here is my problem:

When you delete the tasks in right order, everything is right. But when not the wrong buttons will get deleted

So how do I delete a button even when it's not the first one in the table?

```js
var todo = [];
var i;

function newPoint(){
    var newpoint = prompt("new task", "...");
    if (newpoint == null||newpoint==""){
        alert("Cancel...");
        return 0;
    }
    else{
    newCell(name);
    }
}
function deleteAll(){
    var tableLen = document.getElementById("todoTable").rows.length;
    for(i = 0;i<tableLen;i++){
        document.getElementById("todoTable").deleteRow(0);
}

}
function newCell(name){
    var table = document.getElementById("todoTable");
    var row = table.insertRow(0);
    var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
    var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
    cell2.className ="btnClass";
    cell2.onclick = ""
    cell1.innerHTML = name;
    var btn = document.createElement("button");
    var t = document.createTextNode("done");
    btn.id = "ownButtos";
    btn.className = "arrayButton";
    btn.onclick = function () {
        this.parentElement.removeChild(this);
        document.getElementById("todoTable").deleteRow(this);
    };
    btn.appendChild(t);
    cell2.appendChild(btn);
    

 }
```

```css
.buttons{
    background-color: rgb(34, 158, 34);
    color: white;
    border: none;
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
}
.buttons:hover{
    background-color: rgb(16, 124, 16);
    cursor:  pointer;
}
.arrayButton{
    background-color: rgb(34, 158, 34);
    color: white;
    border: none;
    width: 50px;
    height: 25px;
}
.arrayButton:hover{
    background-color: rgb(16, 124, 16);
    cursor:  pointer;
}
.styleTR{
    color: black;
}
ul{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 200px;
}
body{
    background-color: aqua;
}
#todo,ownButtons{
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin: 10px 0;
}
#todoTable{
    border: 0px solid rgb(89, 0, 255);

}
.btnClass{
    background-color:rgb(34, 158, 34);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="Todo.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="sly.css">
</head>
<body>
<ul>
    <button id="style" class="buttons" onclick="newPoint();">new task</button>
    <button id="style" class="buttons" onclick="deleteAll();">delete list</button>
</ul>
</table>
<table id="todoTable" border="2px">
    <tr>
    </tr>
</table>

<h3 id="todo"></h3>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the `btn.click`.

Replace it with

`btn.click = document.getElementById("todoTable").deleteRow(this.parentElement.parentElement.rowIndex);`

For `deleteRow` i am passing the index of the task which is clicked.